# How to preserve aspect ratio in mencoder

Tags: video, mencoder, aspect-ratio

I converted a video with mencoder and kept the same height and width, but the video aspect ratio looks different. I think this is related to PAR and DAR. Here is the information from ffmpeg about the original file:

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42isomavc1
    encoder         : HandBrake 3925svn 2011041501
  Duration: 00:04:00.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1211 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 720x352 [PAR 10384:11745 DAR 472:261], 1046 kb/s, PAR 137588:176175 DAR 6254:3915, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 159 kb/s
```

This is information about the file converted by mencoder:

```
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : MEncoder SVN-r32739-4.2.1
  Duration: 00:03:59.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3447 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mpeg4, yuv420p, 720x352 [PAR 1:1 DAR 45:22], 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 29.97 tbn, 30k tbc
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_s16le, 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1536 kb/s
```

Why does the video look different even though they are both 720x352? How can it be fixed?

Comment: And how do you convert the file? (Which options, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried playing in a different video player?

Comment: As stated above, the args and switches used would be helpful. AFAIK mencoder has a --sar switch which you can use to specify aspect ratio